# Libgdx IOS in Android Studio in mac

Tags: ios, android-studio, libgdx, ios-simulator, robovm

I have imported  latest Libgdx projects in Android Atudio. Successful ran android and desktop projects. Problem is when running IOS project it is showing error's  saying unsatiadied link error.  and when I ran from terminal it just stucked at 93% building.

What i get is robovm is not properly plugged into android studio. 
I have tried disabling the html project build. Still same result.

Comment: Have you checked out the wiki page on this? https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Deploying-your-application#deploy-to-ios

Comment: Yes i have,  but it's about deploying in IOS. I Am trying to run it in IOS simulator in android studio.